# Real solution of Kummer's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville, kummer-theory

I'm trying to solve a particular differential equation:

$$(c*z+d)*y''(z)+c*y'(z)=(a*z+b)*y(z)$$

wherea, b, c and d are constant and y is a function of z.

This is a particular Sturm-Liouville differential equation (= Kummer's equation apparently). I find a perfectly suitable solution in terms of confluent hypergeometric function of the first and second kind when $c$ and $a$ are $>0$ (thanks wolframalpha!).

Unfortunately whein either $c$ or $a$ are negative, ro real solution appears because somewhere in the solution I always have $\sqrt{a}$ or $c^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Is it possible that no real solutions exist for this particular differential equation ?

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $t$ and means $*$ times? And are $a,b,c,z,d$ constants?

Comment: a, b c and d are constant. y is a function of z (now specified in the question)